# JavaScript Chaining Promises : Calling next promise before previous has finished

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Tools: JavaScript ES6

I haven't seen a good succinct answer about the syntax of chaining multiple promises to execute in order. I thought this would be a good nail in the coffin question for all promise newbies out there. :)

My Issue is that I want to call this in a synchronous order `getPosts--->getThreads--->initializeComplete()`

Here is what I am doing.

```
userPromise.then(getPostsPromise).then(getThreadsPromise).then(initializeComplete());
```

- **userPromise** is Promise obj I returned from another part of the code
- **getPostsPromise** returns a Promise and makes a fetch to the server for posts
- **getThreadsPromise** returns a Promise and makes a fetch to the server for threads
- **initializeComplete** is a callback to tell my program that it is initialized.

Here is an example of one of the promises in the chain:

```
var getPostsPromise = function(){
    //Firebase is just a simple server I'm using
    var firebasePostsRef = new Firebase("https://myfburl.firebaseio.com/posts");
    var postsRef = firebasePostsRef.child(localPlace.key);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      //Below is a Firebase listener that is called when data is returned
      postsRef.once('value', function(snap,prevChild) {
            var posts = snap.val();
            AnotherFile.receiveAllPosts(posts);
            resolve(posts);
        }); 
      });
}
```

But `initializeComplete()` is being called before `getPostsPromise` and `getThreadsPromise` have a chance to finish fetching.

Why is that happening and how do I write the promises to execute in order?

Comment: You have to return something from your promise chain to wait for finish each

Comment: @Michael what if someone doesn't need to transfer anything to the next promise and they just need to run in order(btw should I add that into the question?)

Comment: Doesn't matter, just do nothing with it, only the return part is important

Comment: @Michael, sorry if this sounds dumb, but how do I write the return statement since these promises are function calls and not anonymous inner functions like so - promise.then(function(val) {
  console.log(val); // 1
  return val + 2;
}).then.....

Comment: then(()=>getPostsPromise).then...

Comment: Oh  I would of never guessed that! haha. So even if I were passing a value to the next promise in the chain would the syntax look like that?

Comment: Tried this and initializeComplete was still called early :usersPromise.then(()=>getPostsPromise).then(()=>getThreadsPromise).then(
      initializeComplete())

Comment: For starters, you might want to try removing the parenthesis from  `initializeComplete()`...

Comment: Also, can you put up the implementation of one of these promise functions? LIke the `getPostsPromise` function.

Comment: @yts I added in an implementation of the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

initializeComplete is getting called right away because you are invoking it when passing it to `then`. You have to omit the parentheses, just like you did for `getPostsPromise` and `getThreadsPromise`

```
userPromise.then(getPostsPromise).then(getThreadsPromise).then(initializeComplete);
```

Comment: This seems like the simple answer here.

Comment: This worked for me! Thx a TON everybody for the help. So no return value is needed in the chain when the method returns a new Promise?

Comment: Yes, the code you had was fine. Just had that little parens mistake. When the function you pass in returns a promise, the next function passed in will wait for that promise to be resolved and will get passed the value you resolved the previous promise with. Check out this article if you haven't already http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/. Thanks Matthew for making me aware of this.

Comment: the return value of the method is a promise

Comment: Thanks to both of you @yts and Matthew this will be a very useful for others who will eventually need it.

Answer (score 4):

While yts's answer is correct (the issue is you're invoking initializeComplete instead of passing the function), I'd rather format the calls a bit differently. Having each callback function call the next function is a bit against the design of promises. I'd rather each function return a promise, and then call `then` on the returned promise:

```
userPromise
.then(function(){
  return getPostsPromise()
}).then(function(){
  return getThreadsPromise()
}).then(function(){
  return initializeComplete();
});
```

or to pass the actual returned objects and not have to do any additional intermediate processing:

```
userPromise
.then(getPostsPromise)
.then(getThreadsPromise)
.then(initializeComplete);
```

Comment: This method would still be synchronous, it would call getPostsPromise, once that promise gets resolved it would call getThreadsPromise and once that promise gets resolved calls initializeComplete

Comment: Ah, yes you're correct. I didn't know about the magic that waits for the promise if that's what's returned in the `then` function. Cool :) Edited my answer.

Comment: When I do it this way the things I "resolve" in the Promises are undefined in the next promise. How do I pass it along using the format above?

Comment: you could provide each of the functions with the parameters and pass that through to the next function. Or do like userPromise.then(getPostsPromise). which will pass the response of userPromise to getPostPromise

Comment: If you have no custom arguments for the functions, there is no reason to be more verbose like this than what the yts answer shows.  This does not change the behavior and just makes more code.

Comment: In the question getPostsPromise doesn't take any arguments, so I decided to show an example where args weren't passed to the functions, I added additional code that does pass the returned values to the functions.

Comment: The second code example you added (the simple one) has exactly the same behavior as your first code example - except that in the second example, nothing is passed to the functions from the previous promises.  It is unclear from the OP's question (since they don't include the code for the actual functions) if those functions needs the results of the previous promises, but the simpler second option at least gives those functions the option of using that info.

Comment: the same behavior and then describing the difference in the behavior is odd, I did base the first example on the provided definition of getPostsPromise, but regardless, both ways ideally provide the OP with additional understanding of promises and different ways to use them

Comment: @jfriend00 It's true, I didn't mention passing the resolve values down, that's because that aspect worked originally but the promises weren't being executed synchronously, then when I used the  answer@Matthew Arkin it was executing in order but the the resolve value wasn't being passed on.